# Compiling in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

Every time I try to compile this code in OpenCV, I keep getting this error. All I want to do is create a window:

```
//#include <iostream>
//#include <stdio.h>
#include "highgui.h"

int main() {
    int cvNamedWindow(const char* name, int flags = CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    {
        cvNamedWindow("sample");
    }
    cvDestroyWindow("sample");    
}
```

However I'm getting this error:

> window.cpp:4:21: fatal error: highgui.h: No such file or directory

I have checked in the necessary folder and `highgui.h` is very much installed.

Any help?

Comment: What are your include directories?

Comment: they are in my opencv folder

Comment: Your compiler has a list of directories called "Include directories", where it will search for the header files.  You need to put OpenCV's include directory in that list.  Otherwise the compiler won't fint the header.

Comment: I'm using the 'g++' compile command. What would the compile folder be called?

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html

Comment: I've checked usr/local/include and the opencv 'include' folder is there

Answer (score 1):

Include files as following

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
```

And compile the file

```
g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` filename `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

Comment: Getting this error:window.cpp:5:41: fatal error: opencv2/highgui/highgui.h.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Comment: What platform are you using? Windows or Linux? How did you install OpenCV? through package manager or compiled it?

Comment: can you check /usr/local/lib and /usr/lib for OpenCV files?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and i have checked both directories and the opencv files are there

Answer (score 1):

If you have the OpenCV include as part of the include path, it should be

`#include "opencv/highgui.h"`

or

`#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"`

depending on you using the c or c++

Comment: i'm using C, so the first one?

Comment: Grrr even after showing using this compile command 

           g++ -o window window.cpp -I/usr/include/opencv

I'm now getting this error!:

           window.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to  `cvNamedWindow'

           window.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `cvDestroyWindow'

Comment: The unnamed references is because the linker can't find the library or you're not telling which library to use, mainly "opencv_highgui243d.lib".  Currently using windows and not linux.  But works when I add the following libraries. opencv_core243d.lib, opencv_highgui243d.lib, comctl32.lib, zlibd.lib